# Powershell one-liner to show process on same line as port using netstat issue

Tags: powershell, script, netstat

First I just want to make sure user Erik Bitemo gets credit for the original code I'm using here. The output is what I'm looking for with one exception: One of the ports disappears and "System System5" show up in its place and I can't figure out why it's happening.

Goal: Show all TCP (Listening) and UDP ports and the process associated with each on same line.

One liner being used:

```
$nets = netstat -bano|select-string 'LISTENING|UDP'; foreach ($n in $nets)    {    $p = $n -replace ' +',' ';    $nar = $p.Split(' ');    $pname = $(Get-Process -id $nar[-1]).ProcessName;    $n -replace "$($nar[-1])","$($ppath) $($pname)";     }
```

Example Output:

> TCP 0.0.0.0:135 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING svchost
>   TCP 0.0.0.0: System System5 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING System
>   TCP 0.0.0.0:623 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING LMS

The port that it changes is 445 but I have no idea why it's changing only that one when the rest of the ports are working as intended. Why is the script changing 445 to "System System5"?

Using other tools is unfortunately not possible so I'm limited to using built-in Windows tools.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide the raw output from `netstat -bano|select-string 'LISTENING|UDP'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$p` could be something like `TCP 0.0.0.0:445 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 4` and `$nar[-1]` is string `4` so `-replace` operator takes **all** `4`s:

```
TCP 0.0.0.0:445 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 4
            ↑↑                      ↑
```

Force replacing only last occurrence of `$nar[-1]` using *end of line* anchor (escaped `$`):

```
$p -replace "$($nar[-1])`$","$ppath $pname"
```

Read as well Matt's answer to [Replacing last occurrence of substring in string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437855/3439404) at stackoverflow.

BTW:

- `$ppath` is not defined…
- …and `netstat -ano` should suffice (note that `-b` option can be time-consuming and will fail unless you have sufficient permissions).

Comment: You found the issue for certain. I have offered suggestions for this issue as well if you are curious.

Answer (score 7):

[JosefZ's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1215199/348943) perfectly explains your issue. You are using regex and it is doing exactly what you are asking it to do just perhaps replacing more than you expected.

A side note is that you are asking `netstat` to

> displays the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port

with the b switch. However you are dropping that with `select-string` since that process appears on its own line after the other data. That is not the end of the world but because you can use things like `-Context` of `Select-String` to get that but that will have to be looked at more closely another time.

I would like to offer other suggestions as to what you can do in this situation.

> Using other tools is unfortunately not possible so I'm limited to using built-in Windows tools.

Funny thing about that, do you have at least Windows 8? If you do you could just use the [`Get-NetTCPConnection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection) cmdlet which is essentially `netstat` in object form.

So you could do this which should get you the same information without the hassle

```ps
get-nettcpconnection | select local*,remote*,state,@{Name="Process";Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName}}
```

Don't have Windows 8+? Well then we could improve on your parsing script. Taking it one step further to create object will prevent issue with regex matching.

```ps
netstat -ano | Where-Object{$_ -match 'LISTENING|UDP'} | ForEach-Object{
    $split = $_.Trim() -split "\s+"
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        "Proto" = $split[0]
        "Local Address" = $split[1]
        "Foreign Address" = $split[2]
        # Some might not have a state. Check to see if the last element is a number. If it is ignore it
        "State" = if($split[3] -notmatch "\d+"){$split[3]}else{""}
        # The last element in every case will be a PID
        "Process Name" = $(Get-Process -Id $split[-1]).ProcessName
    }
}
```

If you were limited to PowerShell v2 then you would need to change the psobject and ordered casts

```ps
netstat -ano | Where-Object{$_ -match 'LISTENING|UDP'} | ForEach-Object{
    $split = $_.Trim() -split "\s+"
    New-Object -Type pscustomobject -Property @{
        "Proto" = $split[0]
        "Local Address" = $split[1]
        "Foreign Address" = $split[2]
        # Some might not have a state. Check to see if the last element is a number. If it is ignore it
        "State" = if($split[3] -notmatch "\d+"){$split[3]}else{""}
        # The last element in every case will be a PID
        "Process Name" = $(Get-Process -Id $split[-1]).ProcessName
    }
} | Select "Proto", "Local Address", "Foreign Address", "State", "Process Name"
```

The last `select` statement guarantees the property order, which would be shuffled otherwise, and is the functional equivalent to `[ordered]`

So that will net you output like this...

```
Proto Local Address Foreign Address State     Process Name  
----- ------------- --------------- -----     ------------  
TCP   0.0.0.0:135   0.0.0.0:0       LISTENING svchost       
TCP   0.0.0.0:445   0.0.0.0:0       LISTENING System        
TCP   0.0.0.0:1279  0.0.0.0:0       LISTENING PlexDlnaServer
TCP   0.0.0.0:2869  0.0.0.0:0       LISTENING System
```

Which you can then treat like you would any PowerShell object and filter as you see fit or output to CSV or whatever you need to do. It is structured now.

Depending on your PowerShell version you can also use [`Convert-FromString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string) which takes single line strings and converts them to objects as well. Something else to look up.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Your solution would be ideal but it seems it requires at least Powershell 3 or 4. When run on a Windows 7 machine it immediately errors out. Is it possible to make any changes to avoid this? The error is "Unable to find type [ordered]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded."

Comment: Those casts would cause an issue yes. Easy to address though. I will add a quick update for you.

Comment: The process information does not appear to be available in Windows 2012 (non-R2). Most likely it's also not available in Windows 8.0 either.

Answer (score -1):

More simple...

```
filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"};netstat -abno 1 | Select-String -Context 0,1 -Pattern LISTENING|timestamp
```